# How can I get a Byobu split to reload users permissions?

Tags: users, byobu, tmux

Having updated a users group with `usermod -G <grouplist> <user>` in one Byobu split, I was hoping to be able to open a new split and have the permissions take effect there.. rather than having to kill the whole Byobu sessions and login shell.

Is there any way around this?

I realise one can do an `exec su -l $USER` to effectively re-login.. but I'm wondering if there's a way to get this to take effect for all Byobu splits currently in effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process can change its uid and gid, but few processes do this and fewer let the user do this. Neither multiplexer, unfortunately, does either. With `screen`, apparently one can run a command on all windows using `at` (see [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/853897/334516)). There seems to be no direct analogue of `at` in `tmux`, solutions usually include [parsing the output](https://superuser.com/a/392926/334516) of other `tmux` commands ([a gist implementing this](https://gist.github.com/deshawnbw/2773454)). Another solution is to synchronize all the windows, and run the command (from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704472/2072269)):

> ```
> Ctrl-B :
>
> setw synchronize-panes on
>
> clear history
> ```

Comment: Interesting set of work arounds there, thanks muru. I'm going to go away and have a play with a few of them.. report back.